# Cypress intercept and change the request

Tags: cypress, cy.intercept

I am trying to intercept an a request. This request has a specific endpoint and I would like to change this endpoint.

I have now solved it with the following code:

```
cy.intercept('**/i18n/nl.json', { fixture: 'LanguageForItemEditorENG.json' }).as('Language')
```

As you can see I have used a fixture, but I don't think that this is the best practice. My testcode would be more robust if I can route the request to

```
'**/i18n/en.json'
```

and not use a fixture.

So, at this moment the application is making a request to **/nl.json but I want to simulate this so the application gets the response of the **/en.json. How can I make this work?

Comment: You can update then [`.continue`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Providing-a-stub-response-with-req-reply) a request, but I don't know if it'll allow changing the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [intercept the request and modify certain properties](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Request-object-properties) before continuing.

```js
cy.intercept('**/i18n/nl.json', (req) => {
  req.url = req.url.replace('/i18n/nl.json', '/i18n/en.json');
  req.continue();
}).as('Language')
```

Aside: I don't think that stubbing the response is necessarily a bad idea. If you just need *some data*, then stubbing that data is fine. The only time that I would see that I *absolutely* need a network response would be a true, complete end-to-end test (of which you should have very few in your suite), or if I were specifically testing that endpoint.

Comment: Thankyou for you fast help. Beside that, I definetely agree with your point of view about stubbing. In this case this is for an E2E test.